# Change width of main content when side bar is toggled

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm developing an application where the user logs in to their dashboard. When they log in there is a side bar to the left and main content to the right. There is a burger icon to toggle the side bar which works fine but I also want the width of the main content to change depending on whether the side bar is open or closed. I want the side bar to make up 20% of the page and the main content to make up 80%. When the side bar is closed I want the main content to change to 100% width.

When I toggle the side bar menu the first time the menu closes and the main content changes to 100% width, but when I reopen it doesn't change back to 80%. I'm a bit stuck can't figure why - looks fine to me.

```
<template>
    <div class="main-content" v-bind:style="{ 'width': width + '%' }">
    <div id="burger" :class="{ 'active' : isBurgerActive }" @click.prevent="toggle(); changeWidth();">
        <slot>
            <button type="button" class="burger-button">
                <span class="burger-bar burger-bar-1"></span>
                <span class="burger-bar burger-bar-2"></span>
                <span class="burger-bar burger-bar-3"></span>
            </button>                           
        </slot>
    </div> 
    </div>                 
</template>

<script> 
    import {store} from '../store.js';
    import {mutations} from '../store.js';

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                width: 80
            }
        },
        computed: {
            isBurgerActive() {
                return store.isNavOpen
            }
        },
        methods: {
            toggle() {
                mutations.toggleNav()
            },
            changeWidth() {
                if (this.width = 80) {
                    this.width = 100;
                } else if (this.width = 100) {
                    this.width = 80;
                }
                console.log(store.isNavOpen);
                console.log(this.width);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's:

`if (this.width == 80)`

and not

`if (this.width = 80)`

The same for `this.width == 100`

Comment: The reason for this is that `=` is an *assignment* operator. In using it, you're assigning `this.width` back to 80, even within the `if` statement. `==` is a *comparison* operator, and it returns true or false, based on whether the comparables are equal.